# How can I $watch a css transition-property in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a resizable dialog, like this: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wcp1231/Jnx6K/).

```
.directive("dialog", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'dialog-template.html',
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
      $scope.movabled = true;
      $scope.dialogElem = $element;
    },
    link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
      /* ...... */
      scope.$watch(function() {
          var width = scope.dialogElem.outerWidth(),
              height = scope.dialogElem.outerHeight();
          return [width, height];
      }, function(nValue) {
          console.log(nValue);
          var width = nValue[0], height = nValue[1],
              content = scope.dialogElem.find('.content');
          content.css('height', height-84);
          content.find('.left-panel')
                 .css('width', width-110)
                 .css('height', height-84);
          content.find('.right-panel')
                 .css('height', height-84);
      }, true);
    }
  };
})
```

But angularjs watch event did not trigger when I expand dialog.

So, how can I $watch transition-property with angularjs?

Comment: Have you checked out $animate? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate it has callbacks that wait for transitions to complete, you'd need to refactor your directive to apply classes but it would work for what you need.

Comment: You should avoid using `$watch` to watch the DOM because Angular will execute your callback at every digest cycle and DOM access is very slow compared to memory access.

Comment: @PhilPrice thx~ But childrenElement's width and height are depend on parentElement. How can I make it with CSS?

Comment: @MichaelBenford you mean watch width and height are very slow, and mouse offset is ok?

Comment: @wcp I didn't say that. I meant you should only watch things that are pretty fast to be accessed (e.g. things stored in memory), and DOM access is arguably slow.

Comment: @MichaelBenford I got it. thx~